# putting a value in a hidden field

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to put the value of id field of $info in my form's hidden field 'info_id'. But every time i put the values in the form field, the info_id remains 0. If i echo $info[0]->id before opening the form it shows the id value but inside the form it doesn't work.What could be the possible problem? please help.

The view:

```
<?php echo $info[0]->Area;?>:</br>
<?php echo $info[0]->Address;?> 

<?php echo form_open('dis_controller', $attributes); ?>
<p>
    <label for="name">name</label>
    <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
    <br /><input id="name" type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"  />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="discussion">Post a comment</label>
    <?php echo form_error('discussion'); ?>
    <br />
    <?php echo form_textarea( array( 'name' => 'discussion', 'rows' => '5',  'cols'  =>  '80', 'value' => set_value('discussion') ) )?>
</p>

<input id="info_id" type="hidden" name="info_id" value="<?php echo $info[0]->id;?>">

<p>
    <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I'm using Codeigniter.

Comment: check your quotes.. i think thr is some problem there..

Comment: i've find the problem..thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon after your textarea.

Not sure that that's the problem, but...

---

P.S. If you're anyhow using CI's form helper, why don't you use it for the input's as well?

Instead of:

```
<input id="info_id" type="hidden" name="info_id" value="<?php echo $info[0]->id;?>">
```

write:

```
<?php echo form_hidden('info_id', $info[0]->id, 'id="info_id"'); ?>
```

that way it's much cleaner, and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your problem is.
1st, shouldn't your input tag be closed, ie a slash at the end:

```
<input id="info_id" type="hidden" name="info_id" value="<?php echo $info[0]->id;?>" />
```

Then, what's happening if you try to display it?

```
<input id="info_id" type="text" name="info_id" value="<?php echo $info[0]->id;?>" />
```